# Php check if exist account

Tags: php, database, authentication, account

don't know why this check don't even show some echo text ...someone please explain me why. Posted all the code, hope you will solve the problem now... tried all of the codes you gave me but still nothing

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "db_admin";
$dbPassword = "123";
$dbName = "DB";
$dbTable = "login";

$salt = '';

$salt .= substr(str_shuffle(sha1(microtime())), 0, 40);;



$value_user =$_POST["usernameReg"];

$value_pass = $_POST["passwordReg"];
$value_pass = $salt . $value_pass . $salt;
$value_pass = sha1($value_pass);

$logCookieHashed = $salt . $value_user . $salt . $value_pass . $salt;
$logCookieHashed = sha1($logCookieHashed);



$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

$sqlGetID = "SELECT id FROM login ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetID);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$ID = $row['id'] + 1;

$addAcc = "INSERT INTO login (id, username, password, pwHash, logCookieHashed) Values (\"". $ID . "\", \"" . $value_user . "\", \"" . $value_pass . "\", \"" . $salt . "\", \"" . $logCookieHashed . "\");";

  if( isset( $_POST["usernameReg"]  ) ) {

$selectAcc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$value_user'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($selectAcc)>0)
        {
            echo "Username already taken";
        }

 else   
    { 
    mysqli_query($conn, $addAcc);

      echo "You are now registered<br/>";
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql API's!

Comment: So how I can solve the problem ?

Comment: @MisterTudi - your first query uses `mysql_query`; the second one uses `mysqli_query`. You should choose one way of accessing the database and stick to it.

Comment: Can you write the code how it should be ?

Comment: @MisterTudi could you post more your code before this fragment. that would help us to fix your problem

Comment: [**This will tell you if you have any errors in PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). While this `mysqli_query($conn, $addAcc) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` will tell you if you have any errors in SQL, assuming a `mysqli_` based connection.

Comment: `$addAcc` that is undefined. Where is that being defined? You also need to show us which API you are using to connect with.

Comment: **Post your full code and the one for your db connection** including for your HTML form. You are wasting everyone's time with answers given and they are not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example of your code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "db_admin";
$dbPassword = "123";
$dbName = "DB";
$dbTable = "login";

$salt = '';

$salt .= substr(str_shuffle(sha1(microtime())), 0, 40);;

header('Content-type: application/json');


$value_user =$_POST["usernameReg"];

$value_pass = $_POST["passwordReg"];
$value_pass = $salt . $value_pass . $salt;
$value_pass = sha1($value_pass);

$logCookieHashed = $salt . $value_user . $salt . $value_pass . $salt;
$logCookieHashed = sha1($logCookieHashed);



$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

$sqlGetID = "SELECT id FROM login ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetID);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$ID = $row['id'] + 1;

$addAcc = "INSERT INTO login (id, username, password, pwHash, logCookieHashed) Values (\"". $ID . "\", \"" . $value_user . "\", \"" . $value_pass . "\", \"" . $salt . "\", \"" . $logCookieHashed . "\");";
$checkUser = "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = \"${value_user}\"";
$checkUserResult = mysqli_query($conn, $checkUser);
$checkUserResultRow = mysqli_fetch_array($checkUserResult);

if( isset( $_POST["usernameReg"]  ) ) 
{ 
    if($checkUserResultRow['username']!="")
    {
        echo "Username exists";
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_query($conn, $addAcc);
        echo "Success";
    }
}



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

there might be two reasons
1) mysql and mysqli are two different syntaxes. mysqli is the extended version of mysql. you are mixing up both. use either mysql or mysqli
2)

```
  $sql = "select * from login where username='$value_user'";
  $selectAcc = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $result= mysqli_num_rows($selectAcc);  
       if($result>1)
        {
            echo "Username already taken";
        }

     else      
      { 
        mysqli_query($conn, $addAcc);

        echo "You are now registered<br/>";
      }
```

}

Comment: Perhaps removing the possibility of SQL injection would be helpful?

Comment: Same... nothing happens ...

Comment: can you verify if your $sql statement is working or not in you datebase and can you provide what statement did you assign to variable $conn

Answer (score 1):

> Can you write the code how it should be ? –  MisterTudi

It should be like this.
Using *Prepared Statements*, since *mysql_ functions are deprecated*.

```
//the values in $mysqli are serverIP,databaseUsername,databasePassword and databaseName
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','rootPassword','databaseName');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$value_user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows() >= 1){
    echo 'username already taken.';
} else {
    echo 'username is good to go.';
}
```

Comment: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: have you edited the `$mysqli` variable?, and is the variable `$value_user` set?

Comment: Paste the code with my part in it to pastebin and link it here, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I found the problem thanks !

Comment: No problem mate, you're now also protected against SQL injections :), have fun coding!

Answer (score 1):

As per your [**originally posted question/code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27890846/1)

---

**Try the following code, this will solve your problem.**

```
$selectAcc="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$value_user'";
 $rsult=mysql_query($selectAcc);
$count=mysql_num_rows ($rsult); 
if($count==1){echo "username already in use"; }
else 
{ echo "username is available";}
```

Comment: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/javanpmg/public_html/src/register.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/javanpmg/public_html/src/register.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/javanpmg/public_html/src/register.php on line 42
username is available

Comment: I cant understand why you are getting these warnings, the code is working fine for me. can you add your full code to the question?

Comment: yep i post all of the code

Comment: Don't mix **mysql** and **mysqli** together! thats the main problem in your code!